# How do I enable gtk theming in wine when the checkbox is greyed out

Tags: arch-linux, wine, gtk3

I have installed wine-staging 6.1 from the aur on arch.

When I open winecfg and go to the "staging" tab, the checkbox to enable gtk theming is grayed out

[image]

Is there a way to fix this like a patch or something?

btw I'm not actually new to linux I just can't bother to make an account on this site

Answer (score 0):

The new staging 7.0-rc3 have enabled it.
To make it work, go to winehq.org and install it from there.